# WebRTC SDP in PJSIP on iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc, sip, voip, pjsip

In my VoIP iOS app I am trying to use PJSIP only for SIP signalling and WebRTC for media. I know how to retrieve SDP from WebRTC. The question is how to replace SDP of PJSIP with SDP from WebRTC.

I checked similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880030/pjsua-custom-sdp/11911234#11911234) but the problem is that:

1) pjmedia_session does not available in PJSIP 2.5 (I use the last version of the library)

2) I tried to modify SDP body without any success

So my question is: is it correct way to modify SDP body in my case and if yes can anyone help with more details? If not, is there any other way to achieve my goal?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: "I tried to modify SDP body without any success" What did you try? What did you expect? What were the results?

Comment: Thank you, Kevin!

It seems I have some progress on my issue.

1. I use "pjsua_config" structure. This structure describes the settings to control the API and user agent behavior.

2. "pjsua_config" structure contains "pjsua_callback" structure - application callback to receive various event notifications from the library.

3. I implemented "on_call_sdp_created" callback. It notifies application when a call has just created a local SDP.

4. In the callback described in #3 I replaced SDP generated by PJSIP with the new one generated by WebRTC. 

Now I continue...

Comment: I resolved this issue, but still have some problems with implementing "hold / unhold" feature.

Comment: Hi @IgorNazarov , according to your answer, we have changed the SDP in "on_call_sdp_created" callback. But still it is not working. Can you please help me on the same. If posssible, kindly send me your contact on
"ckchandane@gmail.com"