# python3-pjsip(pjproject2.9 pjsua) custom sdp

Tags: sip, python-3.7, pjsip, sdp

I have a lab that I need to insert a custom body (SDP) in SIP message. I'm using python3-pjsip(pjproject2.9) to create simple SIP UA. However, python3-pjsip(pjproject2.9) does not support custom SDP. I found that someone raise a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880030/pjsua-custom-sdp) about pjsua custom SDP on stack overflow and solved it. Unfortunately, I don't know how to modify the pjsua source with those tips. Would you tell me how to modify it in more detail or share the source you modified? .

Could I need to modify the C code?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used PJSIP in Python, but I think you should look into `on_call_sdp_created` callback. There you should use `pjmedia_sdp_media` structure to add new SDP parameter to `pjmedia_sdp_session` provided by callback's argument. Functions `pjmedia_sdp_attr_create` and `pjmedia_sdp_media_add_attr` also should be helpful there.

Good luck!